# Prevent a flex items height from expanding to match other flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two elements inside a container, which are being side-by-side by using flex box. On the second element (`.flexbox-2`), I am setting it's height in the CSS. However, then the first element (`.flexbox-1`) will match the height of `.flexbox-2`. How would I stop `.flexbox-1` from matching the height of `.flexbox-2`, and instead just retain its natural height?

Here is what I have so far (also available [as a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yb73cn9/))

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}
.flexbox-1 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: solid 3px red;
}
.flexbox-2 {
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  border: solid 3px blue;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox-1">.flexbox-1</div>
  <div class="flexbox-2">.flexbox-2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: [**How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> **This is an old solution.**
> My answer is superseded by this [new answer by Aaron using `align-self`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156422/2930477). That is a better solution that does not rely on a CSS quirk.

As long as the flex container **has no height itself**, you can set `height: 0%` on the first flex item. Because it has no height to inherit from its parent, any *percentage* height will cause it to collapse. It will then grow with its contents.

#### Example

In this example I have removed the `-webkit` prefix. [It's only really required for Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and the prefix can be added *above* the non-prefixed version. I also removed `flex-direction: row` as it is the default value.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox-1 {
  flex: 1;  
  height: 0%;  
  border: solid 3px red;
}
.flexbox-2 {
  flex: 2;
  border: solid 3px blue;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox-1">.flexbox-1</div>
  <div class="flexbox-2">.flexbox-2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 227):

I know this is an old question but a better solution is to set the flex item to align to the top using `flex-start`.

```css
/* Default Styles */
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox-2 {
  flex: 2;
  border: solid 3px blue;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
 .flexbox-1 {
  flex: 1;  
  align-self: flex-start;  
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox-1">"align-self: flex-start;"</div>
  <div class="flexbox-2">.flexbox-2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note you can also do 'align-items: flex-start' on parent element to prevent all children from growing - needed in my case.

Comment: `align-items: center, baseline, flex-start, flex-end` are working as well

Comment: This is necessary because the default value for `align-items` is `stretch`.

Comment: what does the number mean in `flex: 2` ? like an ideal number of items on a row or something?

Answer (score 25):

You can easily fix that by adding to the parent **align-items: flex-start;**

That's all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a five year old question with existing answers it is important to explain what new aspect of the question you are addressing and how your answer works and why it should be used. Correct code formatting also really helps as right now you just have bold text in a sentence which doesn't provide context about which css rule to add it to.

Comment: Yes, but that would align **all** items to the top

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `height` of the children to `max-content` will prevent them to shrink.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}
.flexbox-1 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: solid 3px red;
  height: max-content;
}
.flexbox-2 {
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  border: solid 3px blue;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox-1">.flexbox-1</div>
  <div class="flexbox-2">.flexbox-2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to utilize "col" element and auto-width feature, which works as auto-height feature when flexbox orientation is column. Here's an example with bootstrap 5

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#equal-width

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on @misterManSam's answer, but I don't have reputation enough.

It worked me well but I had some troubles on Vercel (maybe, I was using node-sass, in another version), setting

```
height: 0%;
```

I recommend

```
height: 100%;
```

It's exactly the same answer, but it works everywhere.