# Flex Center Content but Align to Top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently using Flexbox to layout my website and I'm trying to achieve a specific design.

The design I'm trying to achieve is shown below - where the overall content is centered in the middle of the page but the content on the left is align to the top of the right content. The height of the body is also 100vh.

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [**How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33043084/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `align-items` and `align-self` to get this to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbyBOd

Code dump:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: gray;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`align-self` is a good shout

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child1 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: #3498db;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, voluptatibus.</div>
  <div class="child2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, vel!</div>
</div>
```