# Set equal height for group of divs

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

Within a section, I have 4 divs. The first div, which is floated to the left currently has both width and height in pixels. What I want is for the height to be DYNAMICALLY generated based on the other div's height. I am quite stuck. Here is my jsfiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/ksaluja/62o7ydan/ Thanks!

```
<section>
<div class="attempt">

</div>
<div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a style="background:#3F4E64" href="/html/default.asp">Button1</a></li>
        <li><a style="background:#788291">Button2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <H2>TITLE</H2>
    <p>
        BADKADA
    </p>
    <p>
        Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan, posuere scelerisque lacus ultrices. Quisque quis ultricies nunc. Nam augue magna, eleifend id mi vel, pretium
    </p>
    <p>
        Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan, posuere scelerisque lacus ultrices. Quisque quis ultricies nunc. Nam augue magna, eleifend id mi vel, pretium
    </p>

    <p>
        Fusce luctus Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan, posuere scelerisque lacus ultrices. Quisque quis ultricies nunc. Nam augue magna, eleifend id mi vel, pretium fring.
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <H2>TITLE2</H2>
    <p>
        BADKADA
    </p>
    <p>
        Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan, posuere scelerisque lacus ultrices. Quisque quis ultricies nunc. Nam augue magna, eleifend id mi vel, pretium
    </p>
    <p>
        Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan, posuere scelerisque lacus ultrices. Quisque quis ultricies nunc. Nam augue magna, eleifend id mi vel, pretium
    </p>

    <p>
        Fusce luctus Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan, posuere scelerisque lacus ultrices. Quisque quis ultricies nunc. Nam augue magna, eleifend id mi vel, pretium fring.
    </p>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.attempt {
    float:left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 1290px;
    background: #3F4E64;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have strict limitations on which browsers you must support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this layout with CSS [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Make the `section` a flex container, which converts the divs to flex items.

But wrap the last three divs in a nested flex container. Now the `section` has two flex items, side-by-side, and ***sharing equal height***. No floats or declared heights necessary. Each column will track the other. The column with taller content sets the height for both.

**CSS**

```
.outer-flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.attempt {
    width: 15px;
    background: #3F4E64;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="outer-flex-container">

    <div class="attempt"></div><!-- flex item #1 -->

    <section class="inner-flex-container"><!-- flex item #2 -->
        <div>
            <ul id="menu">
              <li><a style="background:#3F4E64" href="/html/default.asp">Button1</a></li>
              <li><a style="background:#788291">Button2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <H2>TITLE</H2>
            <p>BADKADA</p>
            <p>Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan...</p>
            <p>Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan...</p>
            <p>Fusce luctus Fusce luctus ipsum in...</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <H2>TITLE</H2>
            <p>BADKADA</p>
            <p>Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan...</p>
            <p>Fusce luctus ipsum in dui accumsan...</p>
            <p>Fusce luctus Fusce luctus ipsum in...</p>
        </div>
    </section><!-- END .inner-flex-container -->

</section><!-- END .outer-flex-container -->
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/62o7ydan/1/)

---

Learn more about equal height columns with flexbox here:

- [Here's how to achieve equal height columns with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
- [How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043084/3597276)

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More browser compatibility details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I can use the flex box, but this definitely worked! Thanks

Comment: What's your concern? Why do you think it may not work?

Answer (score 0):

[If you're able to use them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), flex boxes make things much easier on you. You can make the `section` `display: flex`, and move the things for the right-hand column all into the same container. CSS would be something like this:

```
section {
  display: flex;
}

.attempt {
  width: 15px;
  background: #3F4E64;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

...and the HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="attempt">...</div>
  <div>The rest of the content...</div>
</section>
```

Here is a [demonstration JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wkLhsdv/).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting `display:table` to the `section` and `display:table-cell` to the two div's inside it (i.e `.attempts` div and its siblings). Using this you need not set float or height.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2wkLhsdv/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
section {
  display: table;
}
.attempt {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 15px;    
    background: #3F4E64;
    margin-right:20px;
}
section div{
    display:table-cell;
}
```