# Nested flexbox with same height for nested items

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to implement a card pattern (similar to [material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#)) making use of flexbox for layout. Each card has a header and a content and uses flexbox to arrange them.

Cards have a fixed width so if a header is long it will wrap, making that header longer. The problem is I want each card in a row to look consistent, so I want each header in a row to have the same height.

The height of the card is already consistent thanks to the outer flexbox. I don't know how to make the headers' height consistent.

the basic layout is:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-header">
            My header
        </div>
        <div class="flex-content">
            My content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-header">
            My header
        </div>
        <div class="flex-content">
            My content
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Flexbox css:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.flex-header {
  background-color: navy;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.flex-content {
}
```

I also have an example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVMNBJ).

Comment: possible duplicate: [Equal height columns for flex items of different flex containers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36721216/3597276)

Comment: related: [Is it possible to have equal height columns in a multi-line flex container?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36004926/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you want is unique found in only one HTML Interface which is the table. In order to avoid all the gripes and lecturing from everyone about using a table for layout, try using the `display` properties with the values of:

1. `table`
2. `table-row`
3. `table-cell`

For use of these values read [this](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero).

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/dMaBXB?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Add min-height in .flex-header

Example:

```
.flex-header {
  background-color: navy;
  font-size: 2em;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't solve the issue, if a long header pushed the height larger than `min-height: 80px` then one header will be bigger than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to make a same layout as you mentioned and after reading the answers here, that it is not possible with just CSS, I tried JS solutions and found this awesome library [here](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height).

I've created a codepen [example](http://codepen.io/adkanojia/pen/jVgRjZ). It might help someone who's looking for the same.
All you need to do is add the library and use the following jQuery code.

```
$('.item-image').matchHeight({
  byRow: true,
  property: 'height',
  target: null,
  remove: false
});
```

Regards