# Setting a fixed height for a nested, outer flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'll try to set a fix value to the height of an outer flexbox item in a nested solution with no luck.

Trying height, fixed-height, max-height on both flex-container and flex-item.

```
To demonstrate I have create a codepen:
```

[Codepen-Example](https://codepen.io/CodeFreezr/pen/JpqYLY)

Optimal all the cards should be 400px or 80% or evt. windows.height - 100px. (optional).

I tried also a couple of other questions/answers in that direction, for e.g.

- [nested-flexbox-with-same-height-for-nested-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128996/nested-flexbox-with-same-height-for-nested-items)
- [equal-height-children-of-flex-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721216/equal-height-children-of-flex-items)

but in none of them I found the fitting solution.

I hope it's just a simple attribute at the right place to solve it.

If something is unclear, or need more description, let me know in what direction I should enhance the question.

Comment: It is possible to leave a comment for the downvote? So I'm able to improve myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a fixed height on your .flex-item class.
Then deal with the ugly overflow scrollbars (maybe style them rather than just hide overflow, though this is beyond the scope of this particular fix).
I hope I've not misunderstood what you're after.

```
.flex-item {
    ...
    height: 400px;
}
```

Here's the adapted version of your layout https://codepen.io/thejonsilver/pen/PQvZVv

Comment: Ah, thanks for taking my tomatos from my eyes. The trick that solved my issue was to drop "min-height=100vh". Ok, now I can jump into the overflow-challenge <;-)*