# Equal height flexboxes with equal height children of variable content, without JS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Blue container, gray equal height boxes, fixed height images, and variable content white boxes that should be the same height but aren't]

Making the gray boxes have equal height is trivial: `.blue-box { display: flex }`

The images have the same height by design. The white boxes contain variable amounts of text, so they're all different heights.

Is there a way to make the white boxes of equal height, without JavaScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On gray boxes: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`

On white boxes: `flex-grow: 1;`

Comment: I think you mean to stretch the white boxes to consume available space. For it to work vertically, however, you would need to add `flex-direction: column` to the container. Regardless, I don't believe that's the question, which appears to be asking for equal height columns, not how to fill available space.

Comment: Yes, I did the `flex-direction` and it works beautifully. Such an simple and elegant solution.

Comment: That was my original answer, which I deleted because on a second reading of your question, it appeared you were actually asking for equal height for the white boxes, which is different than consuming free space. [It's also not possible in CSS.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36721216/3597276)

Comment: It works in this scenario, which is what I needed. I also learned about the very-useful `flex-grow`.

Comment: Added `flex-direction: column` to my answer.