# Bring two paragraphs to the same position at different heading heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i'm using a CMS and there are a lot of headlines wich are not always have the same row-count. I would like to align the content to the same position next to each other.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}

h1 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>test<br>2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.
      <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically - you can't - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks

Comment: If you're using jQuery this would be fairly trivial to accomplish by grabbing the heading with the greatest height and setting the others.

Comment: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: It's pretty easy with jQuery. I hoped for a CSS-only solution. Thank you. :)