# Add line break if text overflows onto 2 lines

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an E-Commerce website build in .liquid and HTML/CSS etc...
On the collections/category page all my titles have different lengths (some go over 2 lines, some over 1 line).

The problem is that beneath the product title is a Colour swatch and price and review stars and i have 4 columns on a desktop. If the title is really long it knocks the swatch/price and review elements down a line and it doesnt look very pleasing.

Is there any way for the website to KNOW if the title is overflowing down a line and if it ISN'T then add a line break after the title. This way the swatchs/prices/reviews are always inline.

Here is a screenshot of my website and what I mean.[image]

Comment: truncate is the best option, 2nd option you can do to add height for the title so particular space is always there.

Comment: You would need javascript for this. CSS can't detect overflow or linebreaks.

Comment: Note - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can also truncate title by setting a **max-width** and **ellipsis overflow** like this:

```
title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: That doesnt really work for this project as the whole title must be displayed as there are many products with similar names (V1 and V2 at the end)