# How to align images in card with dynamic title?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I will have several different cards with dynamic titles coming from the backend. What I need is to align pictures in a same line, no matter how long the title is, it should be aligned based on the longest title. Here is the picture bellow what I need, and here is the [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xzkL2oqs/) to the code so far.

[This is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N9Hp.png)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.card{
   text-align: center;
   width: 33%;
   background: pink;
   margin-right: 10px;
   padding: 20px 5px;
}

.image {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="title">
        Hello
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/netflix-red-logo-circle-png-14.png" /> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/netflix-red-logo-circle-png-14.png" /> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to incorporate flexbox into the children and then force the image to always be at the bottom of the column.

**Note**...this only works when there are two children...aligning multiple children is not fully supported see [Align child elements of different blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  flex: 1;
}

.image {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="title">
        Hello
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/netflix-red-logo-circle-png-14.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/netflix-red-logo-circle-png-14.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what would be the alternative if I have more children? The thing you suggested with subgrids is only supported in Firefox?

Comment: That's the problem...there **is no current solution** outside of Javascript