# How to make 2 html elements related by height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help, I have 2 html elements **h3** and **p**

```
<h3>Samsung Galaxy F22 launched in India: Price, features, other details</h3>
<p>Samsung Galaxy F22 has been launched in India. The new smartphone has been priced in the mid-range segment. The new smartphone is powered by a MediaTek chipset and features a high refresh rate AMOLED display.</p>
```

These 2 elements are located in a container limited in height and width (w: 376, h: 191)

I use css to automatically add to **h3** and **p** dots at the end

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

What is the main question, how to change the **-webkit-line-clamp** of the **p** element depending on the height\the number of rows of **h3**?

I need if **h3** accepts 2 newline, then only 1 newline should be allowed in **p**, but if there is only 1 newline in **h3**, then 2 should be used in **p** so that there are always no more than 5 lines in total.

*I tried to indicate in the screenshot exactly what I need*
[image]

Comment: If you want to align the content and the containers don't have a fixed height/width, you can use this solution I've used many times: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346340/14776809 This doesn't do exactly what you're looking to do though unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not talking nonsense, I think it's not possible to assign a css with such a condition.

But it is surely possible with a *plugin/library*. But in pure html and css it is not possible.