# Same Height Equal Card Buttons Only Using HTML CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make the button start on the same margin/height using flexbox, but it's not working.

`align-self: flex-start;` on the button class is being ignored. I tried following this guide to resolve the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAJxKnGHcDk

```css
.card figure {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: calc(33.33% - 1.875rem);
  background: #fff;
  /*border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;*/
  margin: 3.125rem 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.875rem 1.25rem;
  color: var(--zwart);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1.875rem 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-body .btn {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  color: var(--zwart);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--zwart);
  border-radius: 35px;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 0.625rem 0.312rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.card-body .btn:hover {
  background: var(--zwart);
  color: var(--wit);
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}


/* Responsive media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .card {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .heading {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .card {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/partners.svg" alt="card 1">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Operationele partners</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          Voor courante activiteiten met de olie- en opslagsector werkt APETRA met raamovereenkomsten. U vindt hier ook alle informatie over onze andere activiteiten en overheidsopdrachten.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/crisisbeleid.svg" alt="card 1">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Crisisbeleid</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          De algemene principes, veelgestelde vragen en hun antwoorden en de wetgeving m.b.t. het aardolierisisbeleid.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/bijdrage.svg" alt="card 1">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Bijdrage</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          Op de hoogte blijven van de bijdrage: op welke producten wordt ze geheven en wie betaalt deze?
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add more details and clarity. It is still unclear to me what you actually try to achieve and what is not working as expected.

Comment: @tacoshy Hey tacoshy, I'm trying to make all 3 buttons start equally on the same margin from the text above. The block 1 has a bit larger text (texts are subject to change, fe be longer) so when i just give a margin of f.e 40 pixels, i want them to line out no matter what content is in it. I will provide more details with a screenshot added because you are right, because of the styling you can't really see the problem on the snippet.

Comment: presumably when you say `3 buttons` you are actually referring to the anchor tags with class `.btn`?

Comment: Assuming `card-body` is a flex-column, you can push the buttons to the bottom with `margin-top: auto` I believe.

Comment: However, you need CSS-Grid/Subgrid to [Align child elements of different blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Ye all 3 a href /buttons starting on the same margin.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes it was explained in the video towards the end at about min 6 but it doesn't work in my code. Trying to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: @Paulie_D not completely. The issue was that the `card-body` was not a flex-column. Beyond that, by default it would not have occupied all the remaining space. So you need to let it flex-grow to fill the remaining space of the card and then it works with `margin-top: auto`. But as he used `margin: auto` it would also apply half of the space to the `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue here is the markup of your code for the cards. To achieve what you want you need to add following changes:

```css
.card,
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

also you need to change the margin of your anchors from `.card-body .btn { margin: auto; }` to `margin: auto auto 0;`.

This will size the body of the cards to fill up all remaining space within the card and then place the anchor to the very bottom of the body. That way they will be always at the same spot:

```css
.card figure {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(33.33% - 1.875rem);
  background: #fff;
  /*border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;*/
  margin: 3.125rem 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.875rem 1.25rem;
  color: var(--zwart);
}

.card-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1.875rem 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-body .btn {
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto 0;
  width: 80%;
  color: var(--zwart);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--zwart);
  border-radius: 35px;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 0.625rem 0.312rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.card-body .btn:hover {
  background: var(--zwart);
  color: var(--wit);
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}


/* Responsive media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .card {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .heading {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .card {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/partners.svg" alt="card 1">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Operationele partners</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          Voor courante activiteiten met de olie- en opslagsector werkt APETRA met raamovereenkomsten. U vindt hier ook alle informatie over onze andere activiteiten en overheidsopdrachten.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/crisisbeleid.svg" alt="card 1">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Crisisbeleid</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          De algemene principes, veelgestelde vragen en hun antwoorden en de wetgeving m.b.t. het aardolierisisbeleid.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/bijdrage.svg" alt="card 1">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Bijdrage</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          Op de hoogte blijven van de bijdrage: op welke producten wordt ze geheven en wie betaalt deze?
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```