# css grid equal height for each element keeping responsivness

Tags: html, css, css-grid, responsive

I have the grid, each element has an image and other divs underneath. Because it's a grid, each element has responsive width and so it scales automatically as the screen shrinks. I would like the images (which can have different sizes and not be homogeneous) of the elements to have the same height while maintaining this responsive feature. If I set a specific height, as the screen shrinks the aspect ratio is not maintained. Basically I need a youtube style responsivness, that is a perfect example. How can I do it?

This is my grid:

JSX:

```
<div className="home-container">
  {elements.map((el) => (
    <Element el={el}></Element >
  ))}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}
```

This is my elementcard:

JSX:

```
<div className="element-container">
   <div className="element-img">
      <img src={imageUrl} alt={title} />
   </div>
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.element-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: fit-content;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element-img {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.element-img > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

PROBLEM:
As you can see, the dish problem is ok when the grid is not shrunk, but then that it does not maintain the same aspect-ratio as the other elements.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks

Comment: What is the expected result if all images have different aspect ratio? E.g. when some are tall, some are wide and some are square?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align child elements of different blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept

1. Create a wrapper around the image to maintain the aspect ratio. Use `position: relative;` and set a `padding-top` to define the aspect ratio.
2. For the image, set `position:absolute;` to position it within the wrapper. Use `object-fit: cover;` to maintain the aspect ratio while covering the entire container. Set `width:100%;` and `height:100%;` to fill the container.

---

### Solution

```
.home-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.element-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.element-img > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

The `padding-top` in `.element-img` is what maintains the aspect ratio. When you set the `padding-top` you're essentially creating an invisible box with the specified aspect ratio. The `padding-top` is calculated as a percentage of the width of the element, so it maintains the aspect ratio regardless of the actual width of the element, which is what makes it responsive.

---

### Aspect Ratios

- Widescreen: 16:9 = 56.25%
- Standard: 4:3 = 75%
- Square: 1:1 = 100%
- Photography: 3:2 = 66.66%
- Ultrawide: 21:9 = 42.85%

**You can calculate the aspect ratio using the following formula:**

> Padding Percentage = (Height / Width) * 100

**16:9 Example:**

> 56.25 = (9/16) * 100

Or you can just use any percentage you think works the best :)

---

### Example

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.aspect-ratio-16-9 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.aspect-ratio-16-9 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x169" alt="300x169 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x225" alt="400x225 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x281" alt="500x281 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x338" alt="600x338 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x394" alt="700x394 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450" alt="800x450 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x506" alt="900x506 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x563" alt="1000x563 Image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Resources

Below I've included some related resources that might be useful to future users for understanding why and how this works, and to reduce issues with implementation and adjustments.

- [Absolute and Relative Positioning](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-positioning-position-absolute-and-relative/)
- [Grid Layout Basic Concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Basic_concepts_of_grid_layout)
- [Padding-top](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-padding-top-property/)
- [Object-fit](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/10/object-fit-background-size-css/)
- [Aspect Ratios](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008538927-Understanding-aspect-ratios)

Answer (score 1):

To Make equal-height columns with CSS grid, set all grid items in a row to the height of the tallest column with the grid-auto-rows: 1fr; rule. To make columns all the same width, use the grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; rule and use the same number of fractional values as the number of columns.

In HTML Code:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>A<br>B<br>C</div>
    <div>A<br>B</div> 
</div>
```

The CSS rules:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #f97171;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #f99e50;
}
.grid > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #f5d55f;
}
```

Comment: It works if the grid is not shrunk, but if it is it doesn't not keep aspect ratio anymore, I update the question to show you the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default height of the image container `element-img` as so:

```css
 .element-img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: yeah but using a fixed height like 100px destroy the responsivness, because when you shrink the width, the element-img width will shrink but the height will not because it will be always 100px...

Answer (score 0):

@C-Gian I tried to maintain the same height for images while preserving aspect ratio in a responsive grid:

1. Set `height: 0` and `padding-bottom` in percentage for `.element-img`.
2. Remove `height: 100%` from `.element-img > img`.
   Updated CSS for `.element-img`:

```
.element-img {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
}
```

This ensures that the images will have the same height while preserving their aspect ratio within the flex container.

Hope to be helpful.

This is my image result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but doesnt work, element-img is ok but element-img >img has 0 height and is invisibile then

Comment: @C-Gian I got it your issue. Could you check my image if it is correct or not? If correct I can share my code.

Comment: it seems correct but It's an image so I can't test the responsivness

Comment: i think this is just use media query to change columns number, it's not what i meant. I'm trying to make the element-container shrink when the display width shrink but keeping aspect ratio.

Comment: @C-Gian I understood your issue. When the display width shrink, the aspect ratio is kept. I will edited asap.