CSS Grid, unexpected gap
I'm facing unexpected gaps when building embedded css grids.
The layout is made of cards (3 cards per row) and each card sub-elements (orange / grey / black into my example) have to be aligned between each other (into the same row). The expected maximum height of a row should be based on the content of it's cells. But height is much bigger than the cells content:


        .cards {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-column-gap: 10px;
        }
        
        .card {
            display: grid;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
        }
        
        .header {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        
        
        .content {
            background-color: grey;
        }
        
        .footer {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 10%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header"> Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 15%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 20%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header"> Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 25%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 30%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>



What do I have to correct to this layout to not have those unexpected gaps?

The issue is grid-auto-rows: 1fr; on your cards... remove that and the extra space disappears. Note, this will not align the contents of the cards to one another, that's a separate issue.

Nah, this is a case where the OP can only get the desired result with subgrid. Example below.

@ralph.m - I'm aware - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711501/align-child-elements-of-different-blocks

This is where subgrid comes in handy. Instead of grid-auto-rows: 1fr;, you want this:
.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    /* grid-auto-rows: 1fr; */
    grid-template-rows: subgrid;
    grid-row: span 3;
}



   .cards {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-column-gap: 10px;
        }
        
        .card {
            display: grid;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-template-rows: subgrid;
            grid-row: span 3;
        }
        
        .header {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        
        
        .content {
            background-color: grey;
        }
        
        .footer {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 10%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header"> Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 15%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 20%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header"> Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 25%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 30%" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>




subgrid is indeed the solution, I didn't know this. Thanks!
