# Flexbox equal height row in a multi row layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been struggling to build a layout with flexbox, and I "think" I've finally got it pretty close. However I'm not sure that the way I layed it out is the most effective / efficient, and I'm still struggling with being able to get a fixed height for the first "row". I need the first row to be able to expand the shortest height to match the height of the tallest row height (for a "grid" look).

I've messed around with trying to set the parent container to display:flex, but that's not doing the trick. =/

[image: Desktop / Mobile Layout]

I could definitely use a review of my structure, as I do have it functional, but it seems like I've gone div crazy to do it, and wouldn't mind a second opinion on how to clean it up.

```css
     body {
         font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size: 12px;
     }

     /*----Flexbox Containers----*/
     .wrapper {
         display: -webkit-flex;
         display: -ms-flexbox;
         display: flex;
         overflow: hidden;
     }

     .container {
      display: -webkit-flex;
         display: -ms-flexbox;
         display: flex;
     }

     #firstContainer, #secondContainer, #thirdContainer {
      flex:1;
     }

     .row {
      flex:1;
     }

     .col {
      display:flex;
      flex:1;
     }


     .img, .info {
      flex:0.5;
     }

     .title, .img, .info, .reviewText, .recommend, h3 {
      padding: 10px 15px;
     }

     .title {
      font-size:20px;
     }

     .lightGrey {
      background-color:#b3b3b3;
     }

     .darkGrey {
      background-color:#5d5d5d;
     }

     .lightRed {
      background-color:#744646;
     }

     .lightYellow {
      background-color:#c2c6a1;
     }

     .lightGreen {
      background-color:#a7c6a1;
     }


     @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
         .wrapper {
             flex-direction: column;
         }
     }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="firstContainer">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row lightGrey">
              <h3 class="title">Short Title</h3>
          </div>
      </div>

       <div class="container">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="img darkGrey"><img src="" /></div>
              <div class="info lightRed">1/1/17<br/>Sally Jones<br/>Snoopy</div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="reviewText lightYellow">Blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah.</div>
        <div class="recommend lightGreen">Yes</div>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="secondContainer">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row lightGrey">
              <h3 class="title">This is a medium length Title. Still pretty short though.</h3>
          </div>
      </div>

       <div class="container">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="img darkGrey"><img src="" /></div>
              <div class="info lightRed">1/1/17<br/>Sally Jones<br/>Snoopy</div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="reviewText lightYellow">Blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah.</div>
        <div class="recommend lightGreen">Yes</div>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="thirdContainer">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row lightGrey">
              <h3 class="title">A really really really really really really really really really long title. Much longer than the previous titles.</h3>
          </div>
      </div>

       <div class="container">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="img darkGrey"><img src="" /></div>
              <div class="info lightRed">1/1/17<br/>Sally Jones<br/>Snoopy</div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="reviewText lightYellow">Blah Blah blah Blah blah Blah blah.</div>
        <div class="recommend lightGreen">Yes</div>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicklaux/mtfnaztp/)

Thanks!

P.S., to give some additional clarity, I'm only looking to have the first row be of equal height, and the 3 columns will be static in nature (no dynamic adding of rows or columns).

Here's a screenshot of what happens with the first row not being equal height, it's not pretty when resized down to tablet size..

[image: Not Equal first row]

So if I could set that first row to be of equal height (without using a fixed height, as the content being loaded into the row is dynamic), that would cleanup the layout a lot.

Comment: Are you interested only in the first row to be able to expand its height? Or do you want all rows to have the same height? Are the number of containers dynamic or specific?

Comment: Apologies, should have been more specific. I only need the first row to be the same height (smallest column same size as largest column in the row). 

No, there will always only be 3 columns, and the number of containers are static.

Comment: [Equal height rows in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36004926/3597276)

Comment: [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Comment: [Equal height columns for flex items in different flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36721216/3597276)

Comment: Thanks Michael, so the short answer is no, I have to used a fixed height, or switch to a grid layout. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Could be misinterpreting the question.

https://jsfiddle.net/mtfnaztp/4/

If you give the containers a column flex direction and a defined height to fill:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
}

#firstContainer, #secondContainer, #thirdContainer {
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest an approach that makes use of [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Please view [supported browsers on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

With grid it can be as simple as this:

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="content">100%</div>
  <div class="content">50%</div>
  <div class="content">50%</div>
  <div class="content">100%</div>
  <div class="content">100%</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows:
    minmax(auto, 1fr)
    minmax(auto, 1fr)
    minmax(auto, auto)
    minmax(auto, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.content:nth-child(1),
.content:nth-child(4),
.content:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}
```

---

Here's a JsFiddle of your example implemented with the above:
https://jsfiddle.net/mtfnaztp/8/

Comment: I will have to check this out in more detail, I'm not opposed to switching to a grid system if that's more suited to the task. However in looking at that fiddle, I'm not seeing how  the first row has equal heights, but again, I'll investigate further. Thanks for the suggestion.