# how to align elements from within two different cards

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I know this has been asked in this forum many times, but I read every topic about it and tried many suggested solutions and still, I'm not able to make it work for my own case.

Here's this case. I have this grid of content cards, but depending on the length of the content or whether or not every element in the card is used, the card has a different height. So, elements are not aligned from one card to another. I'd like to edit my code so the top of each element starts at a relative height so they are aligned.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/louischausse/pen/VRQxgB

I'd like that top of each child div align with each other

Thanks for your help

```css
.section__etudes-card > span, [gr-grid~=row--block], .section__featured-article .hs_cos_wrapper .widget-module ul {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -js-display: flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  align-items: stretch;}

.section__etudes-card > span > div, [gr-grid=block], .section__featured-article .hs_cos_wrapper .widget-module ul li {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
      flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px; }

.section__etudes-card {
  margin-top: 1.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.875rem; }
  .section__etudes-card > span > div {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%; }
    @media (min-width: 48em) {
      .section__etudes-card > span > div {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33%;
            flex-basis: 33%;
        max-width: 33%; } }
    @media (min-width: 64em) {
      .section__etudes-card > span > div {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
            flex-basis: 25%;
        max-width: 25%; } }
    .section__etudes-card > span > div:empty {
      display: none; }

.etude-card {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.9375rem;
  text-decoration: none; }
  @media (min-width: 64em) {
    .etude-card:hover [class*="btn--"] {
      /*transform: scale(1.05);*/
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #e98815;
      border-color: #e98815; } }
  .etude-card .etude-card__title {
    margin-top: 0.9375rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.9375rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.1; }
  .etude-card .etude-card__date {
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    margin-top: 0.625rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
  .etude-card .etude-card__ufc {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #e98815;  
    width: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #e98815;}
  .etude-card .etude-card__cost {
    color: #e98815;
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #e98815;}
  .etude-card [class*="btn--"] {
    padding-left: .5em;
    padding-right: .5em;
    text-transform: none; }
  .etude-card img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 215px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }

  .etude-card__ufc:empty {
      display: none; }
  .etude-card__cost:empty {
      display: none; }

    .btn--primary {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #e98815;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.btn--primary:hover {
    background: #ffffff !important;
    color: #e98815 !important;
    border: 2px solid #e98815 !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="section__etudes-card">
        <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_Ressource_center_element" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1552502647360" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/" class="etude-card">
        
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/34S4L8B/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="image-placeholder"/>
        
        <div class="etude-card__title">
            THIS IS EVENT TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__ufc">TAG 1</div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Place
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Time
        </div>
        <span class="btn--primary">
            See details
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1552496573108" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/" class="etude-card">
        
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/34S4L8B/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="image-placeholder"/>
        
        <div class="etude-card__title">
            THIS A VERY MUCH LONGER EVENT TITLE CAUSING PROBLEMS
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__ufc">TAG 1</div>
        <div class="etude-card__cost">TAG 2</div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Place
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Time
        </div>
        <span class="btn--primary">
            See details
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1551887999614" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module"><!-- custom widget definition not found --></div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1551888011972" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module"><!-- custom widget definition not found --></div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1551888047237" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/" class="etude-card">
        
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/34S4L8B/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="image-placeholder"/>
        
        <div class="etude-card__title">
            THIS IS EVENT TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__cost">TAG 2</div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Place
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Time
        </div>
        <span class="btn--primary">
            See details
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You could use more flex. `.section__etudes-card > span > div {display:flex;}` (then they all have the same height), `.etude-card {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}`, then `.etude-card .etude-card__title {margin-bottom: auto}` (So it pushes everything after the title down)

Comment: @AmauryHanser Thank you for your help... I tried exactly what you said, and it didn't work... maybe I didn't put the code in the right order. What could I do wrong?

Comment: Wat exactly do you want aligned ? Maybe I didn't understand well.

Comment: What I try to do is very well explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568568/unify-and-align-elements-that-are-inside-a-number-of-divs-that-are-in-a-flex-con

Thanks again for your help @AmauryHanser

Comment: The code above transpose to that https://imgur.com/a/UAJaxhc Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser Very close! if the tag boxes could be aligned that would be perfect. I'd like to make all elements aligned and keep the container big enough so the button can be aligned too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is here what you want :**

- All the *events title* aligned
- All the *tag* aligned
- The *button* always at the bottom

**What you will need**

- All *the card* having the same height
- *The card* being a `flex column`

For mor clarity, I'll add the necessary css ***at the end*** of your css.

```
.section__etudes-card > span > div {
  display: flex; /* Necessary for the cards to have the same height */
}
.etude-card {
  display: flex;  /* Necessary for the cards to have the same height */
  flex-direction: column;  /* To be able to push the childrens down */
  width: 100%;
}
.etude-card > :nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: auto; /* Will push the first tag down */
}
.etude-card__date:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-top: auto; /* Will push everything starting with the date down */
}
```

```css
.section__etudes-card > span, [gr-grid~=row--block], .section__featured-article .hs_cos_wrapper .widget-module ul {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -js-display: flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  align-items: stretch;}

.section__etudes-card > span > div, [gr-grid=block], .section__featured-article .hs_cos_wrapper .widget-module ul li {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
      flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px; }

.section__etudes-card {
  margin-top: 1.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.875rem; }
  .section__etudes-card > span > div {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%; }
    @media (min-width: 48em) {
      .section__etudes-card > span > div {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33%;
            flex-basis: 33%;
        max-width: 33%; } }
    @media (min-width: 64em) {
      .section__etudes-card > span > div {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
            flex-basis: 25%;
        max-width: 25%; } }
    .section__etudes-card > span > div:empty {
      display: none; }

.etude-card {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.9375rem;
  text-decoration: none; }
  @media (min-width: 64em) {
    .etude-card:hover [class*="btn--"] {
      /*transform: scale(1.05);*/
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #e98815;
      border-color: #e98815; } }
  .etude-card .etude-card__title {
    margin-top: 0.9375rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.9375rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.1; }
  .etude-card .etude-card__date {
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    margin-top: 0.625rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
  .etude-card .etude-card__ufc {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #e98815;  
    width: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #e98815;}
  .etude-card .etude-card__cost {
    color: #e98815;
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #e98815;}
  .etude-card [class*="btn--"] {
    padding-left: .5em;
    padding-right: .5em;
    text-transform: none; }
  .etude-card img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 215px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }

  .etude-card__ufc:empty {
      display: none; }
  .etude-card__cost:empty {
      display: none; }

    .btn--primary {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #e98815;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.btn--primary:hover {
    background: #ffffff !important;
    color: #e98815 !important;
    border: 2px solid #e98815 !important;
}


/* The changes: */
.section__etudes-card > span > div {
  display: flex;
}
.etude-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.etude-card > :nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.etude-card__date:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-top: auto; 
}
```

```html
<section class="section__etudes-card">
        <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_Ressource_center_element" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1552502647360" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/" class="etude-card">
        
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/34S4L8B/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="image-placeholder"/>
        
        <div class="etude-card__title">
            THIS IS EVENT TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__ufc">TAG 1</div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Place
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Time
        </div>
        <span class="btn--primary">
            See details
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1552496573108" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/" class="etude-card">
        
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/34S4L8B/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="image-placeholder"/>
        
        <div class="etude-card__title">
            THIS A VERY MUCH LONGER EVENT TITLE CAUSING PROBLEMS
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__ufc">TAG 1</div>
        <div class="etude-card__cost">TAG 2</div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Place
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Time
        </div>
        <span class="btn--primary">
            See details
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1551887999614" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module"><!-- custom widget definition not found --></div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1551888011972" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module"><!-- custom widget definition not found --></div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1551888047237" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_module" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="module">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/" class="etude-card">
        
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/34S4L8B/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="image-placeholder"/>
        
        <div class="etude-card__title">
            THIS IS EVENT TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__cost">TAG 2</div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Place
        </div>
        <div class="etude-card__date">
            Time
        </div>
        <span class="btn--primary">
            See details
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @LouisChaussé I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: In fact, I still have a slight alignment issue when I'm adding your changes to my code... https://solutions.jlr.ca/formations/ufc?hs_preview=mLNyxtxx-7338655210

Comment: @LouisChaussé You could remove this line `.etude-card > :nth-child(3)` and this line `.etude-card__date:nth-last-child(3)` and add `.etude-card .etude-card__title {flex-grow: 1}`. It should do the trick. But it will depend if you always have two tags or not.