# is this possible with css to have same heading height in two column layout?

Tags: css

"How can I ensure that headings in a two-column layout have consistent height? For instance, if one column has a single-line heading and the other has a two-line heading, I'd like both paragraphs to begin right after the taller of the two headings. How can I achieve this?"

My code

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cta">
    <div>
      <h2>Quisque libero metus condimentum nec Quisque libero metus condimentum nec</h2>
      <p>Phasellus a est. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    <div>
      <h2>Quisque liber</h2>
      <p>Phasellus a est. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum rutrum, mi nec elementum vehicula, eros quam gravida nisl, id fringilla neque ante vel mi. Ut id nisl quis enim dignissim sagittis. Duis vel nibh at velit scelerisque suscipit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
}
```

https://codepen.io/mukeysh/pen/wvRyabO

Any solution with flex or grid works.

Comment: thats not how grid works. grid aligns the direct child elements. to work that way, you need to make the headers ad paragraphs direct child of the gird

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - How to have children in different parents the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398498/css-how-to-have-children-in-different-parents-the-same-height)