# Align items in list of list

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have some HTML structure like this:

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <h2>Item 1</h2>
  <dl>
    <div><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value a</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value b</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value c</dd></div>
  </dl>
</li>
<li>
  <h2>Item Another One Here</h2>
  <dl>
    <div><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value x</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value some bit long</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value z</dd></div>
  </dl>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want it be rendered as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Item 1
  attr 1: value a  attr 2: value b              attr 3: value c
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Item Another One Here
  attr 1: value x  attr 2: value some bit long  attr 3: value z
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Attributes are aligned to each other based on the length of theirs contents.

How can I do that?

I would avoid change my markup to `<table>`, since they are not really tables. I had tried layout them using `display: table-*`, but that won't work for the title (which should take place of whole row instead of one cell).

Comment: I honestly don't understand the reluctance to use <table> for this particular use case.  What you are trying to achieve is a structure.  <table> is a structural element and built for this purpose.  Everything about <table> lends itself perfectly for the structure you're trying to achieve (particularly column alignment). Tables have a bad reputation because they were abused and used as a style element, but they still have a purpose.

Comment: @RobertWade the OP explained that he didn't want to use `<table>` markup because it's not tabular data, and CSS tables don't have `colspan` like real tables have (for the full width title). CSS grids do offer [a viable way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203811/703717) to create this layout, but to date it's still not perfect. (subgrids are still in the draft spec) In the meantime,  we need to additionally use `display: contents` to pull this off

Comment: @Danield I don't like using tables either, but the example provided is a perfect fit for it.  The notion that "only tabular data" can be used in tables stems from the abandonment of tables as a primary layout tool (which is a very good thing), however the W3C specification for tables says no such thing. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html It recommends using stylesheets for primary layout purposes obviously.  This is a long, old argument and my comment was based on the example provided.  Had OP shown what he actually intended to use in the layout my opinion might differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout is possible with the [CSS Grid Layout Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,auto);
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed;
}

.container li, .container dl {
  display: contents;
}

h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  border-top: 2px dashed;
}


dl > div, dd, dt {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
dt:after {
  content: ':'
}
dd {
 margin-left: 0.5em;
}
dl > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
dl > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
dl > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <dl>
      <div><dt>attr1</dt>
        <dd>value a</dd>
      </div>
      <div><dt>attr2</dt>
        <dd>value b</dd>
      </div>
      <div><dt>attr3</dt>
        <dd>value c</dd>
      </div>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Item 2 - Another One Here</h2>
    <dl>
      <div><dt>attr1</dt>
        <dd>value y -bla bla </dd>
      </div>
      <div><dt>attr2</dt>
        <dd>value some bit long</dd>
      </div>
      <div><dt>attr3</dt>
        <dd>value z</dd>
      </div>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Item 3 - Another One Here</h2>
    <dl>
      <div><dt>attr1</dt>
        <dd>value x</dd>
      </div>
      <div><dt>attr2</dt>
        <dd>value some much longer</dd>
      </div>
      <div><dt>attr3</dt>
        <dd>value z - blabl bla</dd>
      </div>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(**[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/MOJooj?editors=1100)**)

The difficulty here is since the `li` and `dl` elements aren't direct children of the grid container - you can't apply grid properties to it.

Grid Layout Module Level 2 - [Subgrids](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#subgrids) (currently a draft spec) are supposed to solve this problem, but in the meantime we can use `display:contents` to overcome this.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890585/703717) for more details.

---

If your markup was flat to begin with, then you wouldn't need `display: contents` and CSS grid module could do this fine:

### [Cross-browser demo (With 'flat' markup')](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/xPdBRZ?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,auto);
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed;
}

h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  border-top: 2px dashed;
}

dl, dt, dd {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
dt:after {
  content: ':'
}
dd {
 margin-left: 0.5em;
}
dl:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
dl:nth-of-type(3n + 2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
dl:nth-of-type(3n) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <dl><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value a</dd></dl>
    <dl><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value b</dd></dl>
    <dl><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value c</dd></dl>
  <h2>Item 2 - Another One Here</h2>
    <dl><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value x</dd></dl>
    <dl><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value some bit long</dd></dl>
    <dl><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value z</dd></dl>
  <h2>Item 3 - Another One Here</h2>
    <dl><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value x</dd></dl>
    <dl><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value some much much much longer</dd></dl>
    <dl><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value z</dd></dl>
</div>
```

**NB:**

In order to 'shrink-wrap' the grid I applied `display: inline-grid` to the grid container.

Comment: Maybe i will flatten my markup use `<dl><dt>Item 1</dt><dd><span>attr</span><span>value</span></dd><dt>Item 2</dt>...</dl>` to avoid `display: content`. Anyway, it seems a great idea. thanks.

Comment: @tsh I added a cross-browser demo with flat markup and also found a better way to shrink-wrap :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add display inline block to all your values...

```css
dl *{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <h2>Item 1</h2>
  <dl>
    <div><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value a</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value b</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value c</dd></div>
  </dl>
</li>
<li>
  <h2>Item Another One Here</h2>
  <dl>
    <div><dt>attr1</dt><dd>value x</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr2</dt><dd>value some bit long</dd></div>
    <div><dt>attr3</dt><dd>value z</dd></div>
  </dl>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used float to align the items

```css
.f{
 float:left;
 margin:10px;
}

.c{
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <hr>
<li>
 
  <h2>Item 1</h2>
  <dl>
    <div class="f">attr1 value a</div>
<!--   <div class="c"></div> -->
    <div class="f">attr2 value b</div>
    <div class="f">attr3 value c</div>
  </dl>
 <div class="c"></div>
</li>
 <hr>
<li>
  <h2>Item Another One Here</h2>
   <dl>
    <div class="f">attr1 value a</div>
<!--   <div class="c"></div> -->
    <div class="f">attr2 value b</div>
    <div class="f">attr3 value c</div>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </dl>
</li>
 <hr>
</ul>
```