# What is an alternative to css subgrid?

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm working on a page with a pretty simple layout - basically a data table, but using grid layout so that the columns will adjust nicely depending on content size. I want to make the rows sortable (using jQuery), so I need to find a way to wrap all the cells of a same row in a container.

```
display: subgrid;
```

I've tried using subgrid but it seems it's not much supported at the moment.. Obviously, just nesting a grid doesn't work as it won't sync the column sizes between different grids..

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Here is my pen so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEjqgx

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816752/equal-height-of-elements-inside-grid-item-with-css-grid-layout

Comment: related: [Positioning content of grid items in primary container (subgrid feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276)

Comment: https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/03/16/subgrid-moved-to-level-2-of-the-css-grid-specification/

Comment: Chrome intends to release subgrid in v117 (maybe a few months away): https://chromestatus.com/feature/5663795354533888

Answer (score 45):

Depending on the context, [`display: contents`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents) may be a viable workaround for `display: subgrid`.

From [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents): (bold mine)

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they
>   were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element
>   itself. **This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored
>   when using CSS grid** or similar layout techniques.

The big win here is that we can keep our current markup - which groups together each row of data - while keeping components of each row synced together because they are part of just one CSS grid - the grid container.

Regarding [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents): `display: contents` is supported by Chrome, Firefox and iOS 11.4+.

So getting back to the OP's sample Codepen, we can make use of `display: contents` to implement the desired result by:

1) Moving the grid container properties to the globalWrapper div and

```
#globalWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr max-content;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}
```

2) setting the rowWrapper divs with `display: contents`

```
.rowWrapper {
  display: contents;
}
```

### [Updated Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/xprwbL)

Comment: Thanks! This will only work for firefox though from what I understand, right?

Comment: @Buno Correct, however Chrome also supports this behind a flag. I'm guessing that support for `display: contents` will improve long before `display: subgrid` will be supported.... but y'never know :)

Comment: Thank you Danield! Here is my experiment with "display: contents": https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/Lxfyghz6/ -- It's a centered one-column design where the column width is determined by which one is wider, the header or the page content. This is achieved by putting both into a grid. Since subelements determine the widths, I'd use subgrids, until it's supported I solved the problem using "display: contents".

Comment: dude.. omg thank you so much. I'm sitting here reading about subgrids and wondering why they are still not being used and I was about to give up. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Using `display:contents` to simulate css subgrid is a hack: hacks add complexity — making the code harder to maintain and prone to other errors — and sooner or later they will stop working.

Beware of using `display:contents`as a substitute for subgrid: [there are good reasons why it should be avoided](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/20/why-display-contents-is-not-css-grid-layout-subgrid/). Instead use either another Grid in the container element or Flex.

**[Adendum 11/1/2020]** Firefox supports Subgrid since V71, no word yet from the other browsers. There is a [good explanations about the feature in codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/subgrid/), and you can [see some examples here](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2019/04/16/css-subgrid-news-and-demos/). And this is the link [to see the current support in all of the browsers in can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-subgrid)

**[Adendum 06/06/2022]** [Apple announces subgrid support for Safari 16](https://webkit.org/blog/12824/news-from-wwdc-webkit-features-in-safari-16-beta/)

**[Adendum 05/25/2023]** [display: contents considered harmful](https://ericwbailey.website/published/display-contents-considered-harmful/)

**[Adendum 08/17/2023]** It is getting closer: [Chrome 117 Beta supports Subgrid](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-117-beta/), here's a recent updated article by Rachel Andrews on [how CSS Subgrid works](https://12daysofweb.dev/2022/css-subgrid/)

Comment: It is not a substitute for the use cases of subgrid but it has its uses and should not be avoided.

Comment: @thinsoldier the answer with the link is clear. Is the correction to the comment good enough?

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: @jhpratt thanks for you comment: Rachel Andrew's answer is great, and the tests displayed on her page are spot-on, I like to point to her work and recognize her authorship. To that I would add that using `display:contents` to _simulate_ css subgrid is a hack: hacks add complexity — making the code harder to maintain and prone to other errors — and sooner or later they will stop working.