# CSS Grid - equal height of table-alike grandchild cells in visually synced rows

Tags: html-table, css-grid, equality, row-height, grandchild

Is there a way to automatically keep in sync rows height of table-alike structure between headers and body? I mean to force CSS Grid to keep each header and data row to have equal height, despite them having separate parents? I don't want headers and body to share the same column in HTML. I want two main columns: headers and body.

**Additionally, number of rows as well as body columns is dynamic**. The goal is to create comparison table, where headers represent product features **names** and body columns represent product features **values**. Also, table body will additionally be wrapped in `<div>` to introduce a slider feature.

AFAIK CSS Subgrid theoretically would do that, but it's [experimental in Firefox only](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20subgrid)

Below is simplified input code [available also on CodePen](https://codepen.io/ScriptyChris/pen/mdWOqqO?editors=1100). I want "Header 1", "Data 1.1", "Data 2.1" cells to have same height. Same for higher rows, like "Header 2 | higher header 2 | yet higher header 2", "Data 1.2", "Data 2.2" - all cells should have same height.

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

.table__headers,
.table__body {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table__body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__headers">
    <div class="cell">Header 1</div>
    <div class="cell">
      Header 2
      <br>
      higher header 2
      <br>
      yet higher header 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Header 3
      <br>
      higher header 3
    </div>
    <div class="cell">Header 4</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table__body">
    <div class="table__body-inside">
      <div class="cell">Data 1.1</div>
      <div class="cell">Data 1.2</div>
      <div class="cell">Data 1.3</div>
      <div class="cell">Data 1.4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="table__body-inside">
      <div class="cell">Data 2.1</div>
      <div class="cell">Data 2.2</div>
      <div class="cell">Data 2.3</div>
      <div class="cell">Data 2.4</div>
    </div>
  </divc>
</div>
```

In a concise way: **the highest cell in the *visual* row** (because headers and body are technically in separate columns not being same row in the HTML) **should dictate the height for the whole row**.

Below i attach ugly *Paint made* picture presenting what i want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal height of elements inside grid item with CSS grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816752/equal-height-of-elements-inside-grid-item-with-css-grid-layout)

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround by manually setting each row's header `height` (via inline style) to be equal to neighbor row's data `height` with the help of [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) (so these `height`s are dynamically set up when viewport `width` is changed). To make it work i had to switch from Grid to Flexbox for the headers and data columns, because changing `height` for Grid children don't make them "take" (or move into) remaining vertical space (they behave like being glued to tracks they are bound to), which happens in Flexbox.

I am aware this is not the best solution, but i haven't came up with anything that worked better.

Comment: I am also trying to make an equal height product boxes with headers and footers using CSS Grid with borders but no luck so far. It would be nice if you can provide a code sample.

Comment: Well, i think that specific code example depends on specific case. I can share code i wrote for my case and that might help you write code for your case. Here's the exact line for adjusting table row height workaround in my app: https://github.com/ScriptyChris/Fake-PEV-Shopping/pull/29/files#diff-56830e282795532c1103974b1028f39050f59b9662ead528ad8fec13658c87a6R129