# Is there a "subgrid" feature, to position "grandchildren" of a grid container?

Tags: css, css-grid

All guides about CSS grid seem to imply a structure where the elements positioned in a grid are direct children of the grid element itself:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</div>
```

Where `.wrapper` has `display: grid` and a definition of the *grid* properties.

Does it make any sense if I want to position a element that is a "grandchild" of the grid, on the grid itself (instead of relying on its parent?)

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to place `A`, `B` & `C` each on their own row of the grid; would that even make sense?

Comment: This would perfectly make sense, but the current grid implementations don't allow this:(. This is a well-known limitation, there was a subgrid proposal to solve it, but it was [hard to implement](https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2016/02/12/subgrids-thinking-out-loud/), so it was postponed for the future CSS Grid Level 2 spec. To some extent, it can be solved by using `display:contents` for the child whose children should be placed in the grid, but it's currently supported only by Firefox, WebKit TP, and Chrome behind the flag.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn That's an answer, I'd post that. It's a good marker for similar questions.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I would also accept that as an answer. "In a grid, only direct children are grid items and can be positioned on the grid. " (a line from the igalia article) is what I wish was printed in red at the very top of every guide about grid. *sigh*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### `display: subgrid`

*From the [CSS Grid Level 2 draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/):*

> [**2. Grid Containers**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#grid-model)
>
> Subgrids provide the ability to pass grid parameters down through nested elements, and content-based sizing information back up to their parent grid.
>
> If the element is a grid item (i.e. it is in-flow and its parent is a
>   grid container), `display: subgrid` makes the element a subgrid (which is a
>   special type of grid container box) and consequently ignores its
>   `grid-template-*` and `grid-*-gap` properties in favor of adopting the
>   parent grid tracks that it spans.
>
> [**3. Subgrids**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#subgrids)
>
> A grid item can itself be a grid container by giving it `display: grid`. In this case the layout of its contents will be independent of the layout of the grid it participates in.
>
> In some cases it might be necessary for the contents of multiple grid items to align to each other. A grid container that is itself a grid item can defer the definition of its rows and columns to its parent grid container by using `display: subgrid`, making it a subgrid.
>
> In this case, the grid items of the subgrid participate in sizing the grid of the parent grid container, allowing the contents of both grids to align. [Read more.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#subgrids)

This feature has not yet been implemented in major browsers. Who knows when it will be.

In Grid, only the in-flow children of the container become grid items and can accept grid properties.

With `display: subgrid` on a grid item, the children of the item respect the lines of the container.

According to the [Grid Level 1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#major-2016), `display: subgrid` has been deferred to [Level 2](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2).

For now, `display: grid` on grid items (i.e., nested grid containers) may be useful in some cases.

Another possible workaround is `display: contents`. The method is explained here:

- [What is an alternative to css subgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48050939/3597276)

More information:

- https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2016/02/12/subgrids-thinking-out-loud/
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1240834

Comment: I accept for the "display: subgrid" part, which essentially means "no, that's not possible yet" :)

Comment: Subgrid is now implemented in Firefox 69+. Nowhere else, though, so still not usable.

Comment: As of today, `subgrid` is supported in Safari 16.0+ and [is currently still in the development phase for Chrome](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5663795354533888)

Comment: As of September 2023 `subgrid` is supported in all evergreen browsers

Answer (score 8):

Since [subgrids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid) are not supported at all, as of writing this answer, [on browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid#browser_compatibility) other than latest *Firefox v71*, and even if other browsers would start supporting it, still, users with older versions will be left behind for at least a year until enough users upgrade their browsers to be able to use such a new feature.

**I've devised a method for aligning deeply-nested grid elements on an ancestor grid:**

At its essence, this solution is about applying [`display:contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box) to all nested elements of the grid, up to the ones wished to be used as the grid items, which effectively does an inverse-inheritance, so every element set with `display:contents` is actually projecting its child's display, so ultimately the deeply-nested elements are treated as if they were direct children of the `.container` element.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container div{
  display: contents; /* <-- makes the div elements "transparent" to the grid */
}

input{ height: 40px; }
label{ align-self: center; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label contenteditable>very long label</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label contenteditable>short</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is treated by the browser as if:

```html
<div class="container">
  <label contenteditable>very long label</label>
  <input>
  <label contenteditable>short</label>
  <input>
</div>
```

---

In the above example the labels are editable to showcase the dynamic nature of the grid tracks, so all grid items are aligned.

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/VwzLLvy)

Comment: This is really useful for satisfying certain grid layouts when used with loops in React. If a design requires each list item to output multiple elements but still stay aligned to the grid, React unfortunately will want an extra container for each item since each child requires a unique key. That extra container React wants will cause the children not to be aligned, but this fixes that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what is "extra item" mean. Why would React would "want" that? I'm a React PRO and you do **not** need ever any extra container, unless you're returning raw string in the JSX iteration

Comment: I've gotten so used to the shorthand for React Fragments that I forgot we could set a key on the actual Fragment component if we import it.   You pushing back on that just made me remember. Thank you