# Nested CSS grid layout different behavior in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS grid layout to simulate some responsive behavior, specifically with:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
```

My example https://codepen.io/elgs/pen/goNxeL works well in Chrome, however, it doesn't seem to work in Firefox. You will find it when you resize the browser horizontally.

Another example https://codepen.io/elgs/pen/YYoxOq works well in both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
}
.header {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #57324f;
}
.header .title {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: aliceblue;
}
.footer {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #57324f;
}
.footer .copyright {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: aliceblue;
}
.content {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
.content .main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.placeholder {
    height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="copyright">
        <span>Footer</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering whether I have done anything wrong or it's the browser's bug.

- Firefox version: 58.0 (64-bit)
- Chrome version: Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *appears* to be a bug in Firefox. But I'm not sure.

Here's what is clear:

1. **The fact that you have nested grid containers matters.**

   Your [second demo](https://codepen.io/elgs/pen/YYoxOq), which works in both Chrome and Firefox, has only one grid container.

   The [first demo](https://codepen.io/elgs/pen/goNxeL), which only works in Chrome, has nested grid containers. If you eliminate that nesting, and use only one grid container, the layout works in both browsers.

   So, as a possible cross-browser solution, minimize the nesting of grid containers.

   In this revised demo, I've commented out `display: grid` on the `body` and `.content` elements. The only grid container left is on `.main`, the parent of the red boxes:

   [revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoBRya)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* display: grid; */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #57324f;
}

.header .title {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #57324f;
}

.footer .copyright {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  /* display: grid; */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.content .main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.placeholder {
    height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="copyright">
    <span>Footer</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

2. **In Firefox, a fixed value on `max-width` prevents the box from shrinking to accommodate smaller screen sizes.**

   Firefox has a problem shrinking the `.main` container with a pixel value on the `max-width`. Chrome does not.

   A typical solution that comes to mind is to override the `min-width: auto` default setting on grid items. This prevents items from shrinking past the size of their content or their defined width.

   However, that solution, described here: [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276) ... doesn't work in this case.

   (Probably because there is no content in and no defined widths on the grid items. The only widths defined are on the grid columns, set on the grid container. So the solution, which applies only to grid items, probably doesn't even apply.)

   As a possible workaround, if you must keep the nested containers, then instead of using a fixed value with `max-width`, use a percentage value. That may work for you.

   [revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEreXm)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #57324f;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* grid-template-rows: 0; */
  align-content: start;  /* new */
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.content .main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;  /* new */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* max-width: 1000px; */
  max-width: 75%;  /* new */
}

.placeholder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #57324f;
}

.header .title,
.footer .copyright {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.footer .copyright {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="copyright">
    <span>Footer</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By changing `max-width` from a fixed value to a percentage, both Chrome and Firefox behave as expected. Thank you so much. Wondering This is Firefox expected behavior or whether they will fix it in future releases.

Comment: You're welcome. Like I mentioned at the outset, I'm not entirely sure about the status of this bug. It sure looks like one in Firefox. But Grid is brand new, so lots of things probably still need to be sorted out.

Comment: RE: Firefox buggy behavior - it could be [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1240834), which is more about deferred implementation of subgrids (aka lacking a feature more than containing a bug)

Comment: @TylerH, that bug report is about the subgrid feature ([which I've explored before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276)). This question isn't calling any subgrids. It's just nesting grid containers, so I'm not sure they are related. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Michael_B I see; I thought subgrids were simply a term for `display:grid` elements nested inside other `display:grid` elements.

Comment: @TylerH, sure sounds like that, but no. A nested grid container and a subgrid are not the same. A subgrid is an entirely separate feature, which hasn't yet been implemented by any browser.