# Why doesn't Chrome (73.0.3683.103) place grid-items of a button in a row when grid-template-columns is specified?

Tags: css

I have this button containing two span child-elements:

```
<button>
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="blue"></span>
</button>
```

The span elements are displayed side by side.

When I add a grid style to the button, the span elements are displayed below each other
because that is the default for a grid. (The css styling code follows below.)

```
<button class="grid">
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="blue"></span>
</button>
```

When I add grid-template-columns: auto auto; to the grid style, I expected
the span elements to be displayed side by side again. But in Chrome
version 73.0.3683.103 that does not happen. Why?

```
<button class="grid columns">
<span class="red"></span>
<span class="blue"></span>
</button>
```

The css:

```
.red { background-color: red; }

.blue { background-color: blue; }

span {
  margin:  0.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height:  1rem;
}

.grid { display: grid; }

.columns { grid-template-columns: auto auto; }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ax21cstf/) is an example.

Comment: its an open issue see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815477/is-a-button-allowed-to-have-displaygrid

Comment: Thank you kukkuz