# How can I use display: grid on button elements?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I wish to style the `<button>` element using CSS grid.

> **I know the user agent stylesheet has some defaults, but I can't find the right one to override**.

It should look like this - indeed, it does look like this if I style a `div`:

[image]

However styling a button looks like this:

[image]

[Here's a demonstration using JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hsr8cLx/2/)

Here's my CSS:

```
button, .button {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
}
```

And HTML:

```
How buttons look:

<button>
  <h1>
    hello
  </h1>
  <h2>
    world
  </h2>
</button>

How divs look, and how I want buttons to look:

<div class="button">
  <h1>
    hello
  </h1>
  <h2>
    world
  </h2>
</div>
```

My styles work on a `div`, but don't work on a `button`.

**How can I style a button using CSS grid?**

Comment: Seems to be some kind of bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815477/is-a-button-allowed-to-have-displaygrid

Comment: From the duplicate: [The `<button>` element is not designed to be a flex or grid container.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)

Comment: Acknowledged @Michael_B - a small note, there's no reference for the comment about display: grid not being designed to work on buttons, browsers just need to (and are) fixing it. Totally agree this is a dupe though.

Comment: Actually Mike, the references are included in my answer. In the listed bug reports, you'll find: *"That is effectively what the HTML spec requires"* and *"Several HTML container-elements are special and effectively ignore their CSS display value"*.

Comment: display can be applied to the children (so no grid nor flex). starting with a reset on margin,padding and box-sizing : https://jsfiddle.net/njx6721t/ go around the bug instead trying to fix it ;) It is usually a bad idea to try to restyle form elemts. they are supposed to be recognizable to avoid tricking the user .as part of the browser

Answer (score 1):

It appears all you need is to add a `font-size` to overwrite browser defaults and to align your `h1` and `h2` left. I'd also recommend  updating `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;` This will allow the first element, in this case your `h1` to be whatever size it needs to be.

```
<button>
  <div class="button">
    <h1>
      hello
    </h1>
    <h2>
      world
    </h2>
  </div>
</button>
```

```
button {
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  background-color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/oqn0x2wp/

Comment: Sorry, I was only looking in Firefox. Some browsers do weird things with buttons, one of those weird things is what Chrome is doing with yours. I've updated my answer to add `div.button` inside your `button` and resolved the issue.