# Center-align an item in a row of two items with CSS Grid or Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is it possible, without adjusting the markup and using either CSS Grid or Flexbox, to achieve the following layout?

```
+-------------------------+
||           ||          ||
|+-+         +-----------+|
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

There are two items in the row, the first aligned left, the second aligned to the center of the page and filling the remaining width to the right. I have tried various ways, such as an empty 3rd grid item with no width etc, but with no luck. This was my last attempt and shows the issue well.

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* for demo only */

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Title</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>| true center |</p>
```

Comment: `the second aligned to the center of the page and filling the remaining width, with a right aligned child` --> sorry but this has no meaing... align to center and fill remaining width ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I have updated the description to make it clearer.

Comment: well it's still confusing :) `the second aligned to the center of the page and filling the remaining width to the right` --> how to align something to the center and at the same time fill the width ? it's not logic

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, that is the question. If you run the snippet the example should be self evident.

Comment: Not possible with the Grid/Flexbox alone, possible with the positioning or JS.

Answer (score 2):

This layout would be a perfect use case scenario for the CSS Grid **`subgrid`** feature, which allows descendants of a grid container beyond the children to recognize top-level grid container lines.

Unfortunately, none of the major browsers support this feature yet. [Technical development has been deferred](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#change-2016-defer-subgrid) and is currently under consideration for [CSS Grid Layout Module Level 2](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/).

More here: [Positioning content of grid items in primary container (subgrid feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276)

Without `subgrid`, the layout is still possible with Flex and Grid, but it can become somewhat complex and may break in certain scenarios. For example, with Flex/Grid, the two outer items can be pinned to the edges, no problem. But the two inner items may be centered, near-center or off-center depending on screen size and other factors.

If you're okay with a bit of off-centering in certain cases, then Flex/Grid may work for you. In fact, you may be able to resolve the issue with media queries, negative margins, the `translate()` function of the `transform` property, or a combination thereof. Again, it gets complicated.

Using only CSS, the simplest solution uses absolute positioning.

(No changes to the HTML.)

```css
header, nav {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}


/* for demo only */
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Title</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>| true center |</p>
```

As an aside, since you're using the semantically valuable `nav` element, there's really no need to use an unordered list. Here's an even simpler version:

```css
header, nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav > div:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

header > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}


/* for demo only */
nav > div {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>Title</div>
  <nav>
      <a>Link 1</a>
      <a>Link 2</a>
      <a>Link 3</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>| true center |</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `subgrid`, after reading into it that seems the correct way to achieve this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I added a class `.spacer` on the second li in order to give it a flex-grow and let it take all the empty space automatically and therefore pushes the last element to the right.

also changed the header styling to `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` such that both elements take half the width.

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.71fr 1fr;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

ul { display: flex; }
li.spacer{flex-grow: 1;} /* or li:nth-child(2) if you cannot add a class to the html tags */

/* for demo only */
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; }
li a{ padding: 5px; background: #aaa; }
p  { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<header>
 <span>Title</span>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="spacer"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
<p>| true center |</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. The links need to be left aligned apart from the last child which is right aligned.

Comment: I updated the code.  I added css for `li.spacer` - in order to give it a flex-grow in order to take all the empty space automatically and therefore pushes the last element to the right.

Comment: This is no different to my initial example. The links aren't centred to the page, which is the initial problem.

Comment: Its better you give us an image on how you would like the links to be rendered and add it to your answer

Comment: Link 1 and Link 2 should be aligned with the centre of the page, which is represented by the "true centre" paragraph tag in the snippet.

Comment: So your end result should be something to the current version? I don't think that this would be the final solution since it will depend on the text length in link 1 and link 2 and also the screen size. You would have to update the `grid-template-columns: 0.71fr 1fr;` according to your text in links 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *hacky* idea:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}
header span {
  min-width:0;
  width:0;
  flex-basis:0%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
nav {
   margin-left: auto;
   flex-basis:100%;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li:first-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right:auto;
}

li:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}

/* for demo only */

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Title Title</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>| true center |</p>
```

Comment: This is no different to my initial example. The links aren't centred to the page, which is the initial problem.

Comment: @DanChristian i told it's confusin :) ... so in yout question you need to say that you want to center sub item withing the container of their parent element

Comment: @DanChristian i updated my code, you can check again

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution the easiest and most clear.

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr; /* magic here */
  align-items: center; /* optional */
}

ul { display: flex; }

span { justify-self: start; } /* magic here */
.right-link { justify-self: end; } /* magic here */

/* for demo only */
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; }
a{ padding: 5px; background: #aaa; }
p  { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<header>
    <span>Title</span>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  <a href="#" class="right-link">Link 3</a>
</header>
<p>| true center |</p>
```