# Same width / height for inner content

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I need to make 3 block same height, same width, not the problem for that. But I need to set the inner divs same height same width for each containers.

Here is an image :

[image]

And there is what I've made so far :

```css
/* NORMALIZE */

/*! normalize.css v8.0.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

 html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
 */

img {
  border-style: none;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */

button,
input { /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

button,
select { /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */

fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  display: table; /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
  white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
 */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
 */

details {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Misc
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
 */

template {
  display: none;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

/* MAIN */

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent!important;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent!important;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}

.circle-big {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #36f8b7;
}

.circle-small {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #081117;
  color: #61ffb1;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.special-orders-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.special-order-content {
  border: 2px solid #0af2bc;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.special-order-content p,
.special-order-content h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.special-order-content > .circle-big {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.special-order-content-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #081117;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.special-order-content-subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #081117;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.special-order-content-price {
  color: #0af2bc;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.special-order-content-price > strong {
  color: #0af2bc;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.special-order-content-price-subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  color: #06cd9f;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.special-order-content .btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #081117;
  letter-spacing: 0.36px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #01f1bd, #64ffb1);
  padding: 18px 35px;
}

.special-order-content .btn i {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.special-order-content-informations > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.special-order-content-informations > div > p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #0af2bc;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.special-order-content-informations {
  background-color: #081117;
}

.special-order-content-informations > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.special-order-content-informations > div > img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.special-order-content-more-informations > p {
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #081117;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.special-order-content-more-informations > p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.special-order-content-more-informations {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="special-orders-container">
          <div class="special-order-content">
            <div class="circle-big">
              <div class="circle-small">1</div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="special-order-content-title">EA <strong>Gaudere Parum</strong></h2>
            <p class="special-order-content-subtitle">Eget et a lactura Mazim suffragari ab me nonin quos ac ac, a Consectetur Secundamut Desiderium Laudare.</p>
            <p class="special-order-content-price">From <strong>$200</strong></p>
            <p class="special-order-content-price-subtitle">This price is a base set price that is unfixable but prices raise as the season comes closer to an end.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Order EA gaudera parum <i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
            <div class="special-order-content-informations">
              <div>
                <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                <p>Rem nec iure te est Simulacrum Quaedam : <strong>Magnae Quae Louor</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                <p>Sem sem eget in dui Nesciunt Vacare ad Ullo</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                <p>Lorem ipsuom dolor sit</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                <p>At si meritorius circumcirca memoria li ille dis ab acerbaaut contemptor</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                <p>Sed elit vero ad Duios Quosed at quo Est Optio’a</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="special-order-content-more-informations">
              <p>*Tempor erat nisi Opprimere / Uidem / Rerum /Quis Bonarum / Typi Saluto / Reprobum Esse illasit ad excessivos novembris ab vel joannes odit metus ea hic exemplo , dolor si ea merentur dui imbellem excindere ex vel exemplo.</p>
              <p>Consulta iste Placida eum simultates superbam et ex SEM Semper orci , eu eros rem oppresso nisi pereunt te EA,EOS,USUS,AD,CUM,cum HAC. Ea modi wisi ruinae non hic vel quam aut arcu haeres.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="special-order-content">
              <div class="circle-big">
                <div class="circle-small">2</div>
              </div>
              <h2 class="special-order-content-title">Proprio 5Incarcerata Ordines</h2>
              <p class="special-order-content-subtitle">Eget et a lactura Mazim suffragari ab me nonin quos ac ac, a Consectetur Secundamut Desiderium Laudare.</p>
              <p class="special-order-content-price">From <strong>$200</strong></p>
              <p class="special-order-content-price-subtitle">This price is a base set price that is unfixable but prices raise as the season comes closer to an end.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn">Order Proprio 5 <i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
              <div class="special-order-content-informations">
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet amet amet</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Mus quo orci te quos usus frustra morbi asylum a Excepto Negabat</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Mi mi amplissima malevolorum nostrae ii tibi dis ea perare</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Nec elit modo a Erat QUO semte sed Leo totam’a</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="special-order-content-more-informations">
                <p>*Axioma eius nisl Perversis / Lacus / Magna / Eius Superue / Nisi Sonini / Opponere Unde elit sit ad consurgunt incusando ad hic quaerat iste class ad est facunda , morbi et ex colubros aut affectus</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="special-order-content">
              <div class="circle-big">
                <div class="circle-small">3</div>
              </div>
              <h2 class="special-order-content-title">EA Animam</h2>
              <p class="special-order-content-subtitle">Eget et a lactura Mazim suffragari ab me nonin quos ac ac, a Consectetur Secundamut Desiderium Laudare.</p>
              <p class="special-order-content-price">From <strong>$200</strong></p>
              <p class="special-order-content-price-subtitle">This price is a base set price that is unfixable but prices raise as the season comes closer to an end.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn">Order EA Animam <i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
              <div class="special-order-content-informations">
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Sem pignora 5 Assum mi redundat modi a Naturom 1+ Locorum</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Quo vel mi eius 7 Magnae Rerum ut Duis Eaquke wisifffflnem/Purus
</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php echo asset('assets/img/stars-yellow.png'); ?>" alt="Stars">
                  <p>Hac dis et sed Facer Praetensionis ullo quod Dulcedo/Eaque ti quo quia</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="special-order-content-more-informations">
                <p>Tempor erat nisi Opprimere / Uidem / Rerum /Quis Bonarum / Typi Saluto / Reprobum Esse illasit ad excessivos novembris ab vel joannes odit metus ea hic exemplo , dolor si ea merentur dui imbellem excindere ex vel exemplo..</p>
<p>Consulta iste Placida eum simultates superbam et ex SEM Semper orci , eu eros rem oppresso nisi pereunt te EA,EOS,USUS,AD,CUM,cum HAC. Ea modi wisi ruinae non hic vel quam aut arcu haeres.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I tried to use grid and flexbox, but didn't found a good way to do that.
The main problem is for the black box in each block, it has to be the same width every where

Comment: May have to wait for the "subgrid" feature in browsers to make this work in Grid CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276