# Make CSS grid rows heights to take maximum of their content

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

How to make css grid rows height expanding to take the maximum depending on their content?

So this would transform:

[image]

Into:

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
}

.panel-grid {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
}

.row {
  background-color: #5879c5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #c5b07f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row3 {
  background-color: #e0ffef;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="panel-grid">
      <div class="row"><div>1</div><div>1</div><div>1</div></div>
      <div class="row2"><div>2</div></div>
      <div class="row3"><div>3</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-grid">
      <div class="row"><div>1</div></div>
      <div class="row2"><div>2</div><div>2</div><div>2</div></div>
      <div class="row3"><div>3</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-grid">
      <div class="row"><div>1</div></div>
      <div class="row2"><div>2</div></div>
      <div class="row3"><div>3</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be possible until browsers support `display: contents` or `display: subgrid`.

In the meanwhile, I think the closest you can get (without altering the HTML) is *equal height* rows across containers. The heights are set by the tallest item in each row.

Add this to your code:

```
.panel-grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* new */
}
```

This overrides the `grid-auto-rows: auto` default.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
}

.panel-grid {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* new */
}

.row {
  background-color: #5879c5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #c5b07f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row3 {
  background-color: #e0ffef;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you can change the HTML–putting all items in a single container– then here's a possible option:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto); /* new */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* new */
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
}

.row {
  background-color: #5879c5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #c5b07f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row3 {
  background-color: #e0ffef;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More details:

- [Positioning content of grid items in primary container (subgrid feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276)
- [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify your HTML and re-order your `rows` (as in the demo code below), you should be able to accomplish something similar by using a container with `grid-auto-flow:row` - like this:

```
.container {
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 9fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
}

.panel-grid {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
}

.row {
  background-color: #5879c5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #c5b07f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row3 {
  background-color: #e0ffef;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid container">
  <!-- row 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>

  <!-- row 2 -->
  <div class="row2">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>

  <!-- row 3 -->
  <div class="row3">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that seems good, thnx. but is there any way to highlight (add an overlay with shadow) to say visual column #2? That was the reason behind `panel-grid`, it's kinda grouping rows and allows me to add nice overlay behind each column.

Comment: @alex.mironov ah, I see... I am not sure... let me check