# Have two elements on 1 row but keep different heights

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to have two elements on 1 row, both with different heights. Flexbox seems to be adjusting the height of all elements when the other element's height adjust.

Any suggestions?

Sample Code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text>Some Content with a longer height</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text>Some Content with now the same height</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Do you have an image or mockup of what you are trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276

Comment: I'll check this out although it might not be a 1-1 because of react-native

Comment: It is 1-1. Wow. Thanks @Michael_B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex box is designed to use the available space that you provide, which is why it is so great for scaling from desktop to tablet to mobile.

[image]

If you want elements in a row to have separate heights, you can simply specify that a flex item have a different height like this (here's a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/ur0pesmd/1/):

**HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "flexCol"></div>
  <div class = "flexCol" id = "smaller"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
   display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.flexCol{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #f00;
}

#smaller{
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  background: #0f0;
  height: 80%;
}
```