# Limit width of children in vertical flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I limit the child width to the content in a vertical flexbox? As you can see by the cyan background, the child width occupies the width of the container. I want it to occupy only the width that it needs.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content{
  background: cyan;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">hello whats up</div>
  <div class="content">hello whats up</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`.

This setting causes flex items to expand the full length of the container's cross axis. (This setting is what allows for equal height columns in flexbox.)

When you're in `flex-direction: column` the cross axis is horizontal, and children will expand the container's full width by default.

You can override the default with `align-items: flex-start` on the container, or `align-self: flex-start` on each flex item.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content{
  background: cyan;
  margin: 5px;
  align-self: flex-start; /* NEW */
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">hello whats up</div>
  <div class="content">hello whats up</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276)
- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)