# Large space appearing underneath my flexbox when child extends past the window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a horizontal image scroll using flexboxes, which I am fairly new to. I'm very happy with its abilities but here is one thing I cannot figure out.

[image: diagram]

So it seems to be fine as long as the parent and the child are within the width of the window but as soon as the child (and also the parent) extend past the width of the window something causes it to give the window some extra height. I've watch a bunch of videos and googled a lot. I don't know this is.

Here's my SCSS:

```
.images {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    z-index:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    .image {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-right: 4px solid white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from the limited information posted. Maybe try adding `align-items: flex-start` to the container. See [*How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33043084/3597276).

Comment: tried your css and couldn't find an issue. could you provide you html too? or perhaps a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I didn't declare overflow-y: hidden. And there was an image in the child container that was making my whole document taller. Yeah, I didn't provide enough information for this question to be properly answered.