# Aligning three elements (left/center/right) inside a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to create a full-width banner with three internal inline elements. A back link, a logo and a forward link.

[image]

I would also like to use the same code to create a full-width banner with TWO internal inline elements. A left back link and a central logo.

[image]

What I have so far, is:

*HTML*

```
 <section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="header-right"><p>3</p><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*SCSS:*

```
#header-blue {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: $primary-blue;
  color: #fff;

  #header-wrap {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    div {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }

  .header-left {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .header-center {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
  }

} // header-blue
```

I am looking for a solution that is widely supported, so I'm not sure if that rules flex out?

**The result is this: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5gxLvp8a/3/)**

[image]

EDIT:
**THE FINAL CORRECT DESIGN WHEN COMPLETE**
[image]
[image]

***Disclaimer:*** *Please understand that although this may be viewed as a 'duplicate' post, after a fair few hours of online research and trial and error, I am still no further progressed. I would, therefore, like to seek help unique to this problem and learn in the process.*

Comment: An image of what **YOU WANT** provided would be better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the layout with [**CSS flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

For clarity and conciseness, I removed several non-essential decorative styles from the original code. I also used compiled CSS for the benefit of those who don't use preprocessors.

### layout 1: [left] [center] [right]

```css
#header-wrap {
  display: flex;                   /* 1 */
  align-items: flex-start;         /* 2 */
  justify-content: space-between;  /* 3 */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

#header-blue   { margin-bottom: 50px; background-color: #3498DB; color: #fff; }
.header-left   { border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
.header-right  { border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
.header-center { border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-center">
      <p>2</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <p>3</p>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Notes:

1. Establish flex container.
2. [Prevent flex items from expanding full height (a default setting)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276). The `flex-start` value will align each item at the start of the *cross axis* of the container. In this case, that's the top of the vertical (Y) axis. If you want the items vertically centered, use the `center` value instead. The default value is `stretch`.
3. [Align flex items horizontally in the container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276). You can also try `justify-content: space-around`. Note that this method will only center the middle item in the container if the left and right elements (the back/forward links) are equal width. If the links vary in length, you'll need to use another method (see boxes #71-78 [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)).

---

### layout 2: [left] [center]

```css
#header-wrap::after {               /* 4 */
    content: "";
    width: 100px;
}
#header-wrap {
    display: flex;                  /* 1 */
    align-items: flex-start;        /* 2 */
    justify-content: space-between; /* 3 */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0; 
}
#header-blue   { margin-bottom: 50px; background-color: #3498DB; color: #fff; }
.header-left   { border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
.header-right  { border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
.header-center { border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-center">
      <p>2</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Notes:

4. [Use an invisible pseudo-element to create equal balance on the opposite end of the container.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276) This is essentially a replacement for the DOM element that was removed from the first example. It keeps the middle item centered.

---

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gxLvp8a/5/)

---

### *Browser Support*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Comment: Hi - Thanks for taking the time to assist. The final problem I still have is the vertical align of the div's themselves within the parent container. The vertical align of the content within each div is fine and taken care of. But - if each of the 3 separate inline divs has different heights, then they will not all be vertically aligned inside the parent. ideas?

Comment: Change the value in `align-items: flex-start` to `center`.

Comment: That's great! I do understand that flex doesn't have great support in IE9+ but, by looking into it more on [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), this solution would avoid the bugs as far as I can see. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

From your structure you could use `flex`(IE11) and `justify-content`, then hide `.clearfix` and remove it when on fourth position:

**with 3 (4 including clearfix)**

```css
#header-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header-wrap > div {
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin:0 0 auto;/* remove if you want each boxes same height */
}
.clearfix:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}

.clearfix {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="header-right"><p>3</p><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**when only 2 (3)** *same CSS involved*

```css
#header-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header-wrap > div {
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin:0 0 auto;/* remove if you want each boxes same height */
}
.clearfix:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}

.clearfix {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

### for older browsers.

with your structure you could use `text-align`, `:after` and the selector `+`:

**with 3 (4)**

```css
#header-wrap {
  text-align: justify;
}
#header-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 99%;
}
#header-wrap > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
}
#header-wrap > div + div + div +.clearfix {
  display: none;
}
.clearfix {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
 <section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="header-right"><p>3</p><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**and 2(3)**  *same CSS involved*:

```css
#header-wrap {
  text-align: justify;
}
#header-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 99%;
}
#header-wrap > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
}
#header-wrap > div + div + div +.clearfix {
  display: none;
}
.clearfix {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="header-blue">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Widely supported - my immediate answer is to use `display: table;`

Let me 'fiddle' around with this for a moment and get back to you - I was just working on something similar yesterday.

EDIT 1:
At first glance, I would advise utilizing classes versus ID's. This deals with a much broader topic (CSS Specificity) but is extremely useful to think about early in your career.  That being said, I am working on a solution for you, as I THINK I know what you want.

As the commenter mentioned - it would help ALOT to see what you want to see as an end result.  From my interpretation of your screenshots (poor quality & non-descriptive FYI), I feel like you want this `header` to maintain the left/back button and the logo on mobile devices.  However, on a desktop/laptop viewport size, you want a forward button to show itself.

If this is incorrect, please verify!

EDIT 2:

Going off the above poster's JSFiddle, I've come up with a "better" solution that stacks the elements within the `header` as opposed to going outside of the 'container' that it exists in: https://jsfiddle.net/f815aa6y/1/

Still working on the right solution to get this to vertically align in the middle :)

Comment: I'll add the design I am going for to my original post. Apologies for being vague - I was hoping to find a generic solution so that I can apply it to different scenarios in future.

Answer (score 0):

Consider positioning the left and right elements differently.

https://jsfiddle.net/5gxLvp8a/4/

```
  #header-wrap {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    position: relative;
    div {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
  .header-left {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
  }
```

See code snippet below:

```css
html, html a {
  font-size: 10px; }

  #header-blue {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: #fff; }
    #header-blue #header-wrap {
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid green;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
      position: relative; }
      #header-blue #header-wrap div {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle; }
    #header-blue .header-left {
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 25px; }
      #header-blue .header-right {
        float: right;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 25px; }
        #header-blue .header-center {
          border: 1px solid red;
          margin: 0 auto !important;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 100px; }

.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both; }
```

```html
<section id="header-blue">
      <div id="header-wrap">
        <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
        <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
        <div class="header-right"><p>3</p><p>3</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
        <section id="header-blue">
      <div id="header-wrap">
        <div class="header-left"><p>1</p></div>
        <div class="header-center"><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p><p>2</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
```