# Prevent flex child from stretching the parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can I prevent child `.title`(pink one) from stretching the parent flex and force it to wrap words? This layout works perfectly when the `.values` are stretched vertically, but on wide screen I would like `.title` to take as less height as possible (in most cases it will contain 1-3 words)

[image: title height responsiveness]

```css
html,
body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.section .values {
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section .values .col {
  border: 1px solid #F012BE;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.section .values .col>div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #39CCCC;
}

.section .title {
  background: #F012BE;
  color: #333;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border-left: 2px solid #39CCCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="values">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">1</div>
      <div class="processed">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">4</div>
      <div class="processed">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">6</div>
      <div class="processed">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">6</div>
      <div class="processed">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">4</div>
      <div class="processed">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">7</div>
      <div class="processed">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">6</div>
      <div class="processed">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">4</div>
      <div class="processed">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">5</div>
      <div class="processed">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">72</div>
      <div class="processed">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">5</div>
      <div class="processed">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">6</div>
      <div class="processed">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="original">5</div>
      <div class="processed">7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">What if title will be long?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would say you cannot since the don't belong to the same container so you cannot create a relation between them

Comment: Not entirely clear to me. Are you saying you want to [**disable equal height columns**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-item-sets-the-height-limit-for-siblings