# How to use `flex: grow` on floating content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I have a header with 2 rows of 2 Foundation columns of content, as below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-5 none show-for-medium columns info">
     Some information to the left
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image">
           image to the right
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.header` height is dynamic and not set. I want the `.image` element to take up 100% of the *remaining* vertical space.

eg:

[image]

To that affect I have tried using flex and flex-grow, eg:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

but had no luck, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kkb2bxu/46/

Would anyone know how I could negate the dynamic height of the header from the 100vh of the image container?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
}

.info {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.image-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <h1>
        menu
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-5 none show-for-medium columns info">
     Some information to the left
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image">
           image to the right
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the second row to take up the rest of the remaining height with `flex: 1` and make sure you nest that flex with `display: flex`:

```
.row.target-row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

Set the `.image-container` to 100% height of its column parent.

```
.image-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

By default both columns will expand. Stop the left column from expanding with:

```
.large-5 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

(`flex-start` reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156422/2930477)

#### Complete Example

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
}

.info {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.image-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.large-5 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.row.target-row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <h1>
        menu
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row target-row">
    <div class="large-5 none show-for-medium columns info">
      Some information to the left
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image">
          image to the right
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, just curious, why does the `.row:nth-child(2) ` have to be an nth child selector? I tried targeting it with an actual class name, eg `large-7` and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MeltingDog - It doesn't :) *but* `.row:nth-child(2)` targets the second *row class*, not the column div. I'll update my example with a class to make it clear :) one sec.

Comment: @MeltingDog - All good! I've updated it with `.row.target-row` to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`flex-grow` only applies to flex children.

`.image-container` isn't a direct child of a `display: flex` element, so that property has no effect.

Plus, it affects the flex axis, which is not what you want.

Instead, you need to put those two elements in their own flex row, and use `align-items` (on the parent) and `align-self` (on either child) so that the first one aligns (on the cross axis) to `flex-start` (stick to top) and the second one to `stretch`.

You'll also want that flex row (parent) to have `flex-grow: 1` so that it stretches along the vertical flex axis of its parent (`.wrapper`) to fill the rest of the page (otherwise, the grandchild will have nothing to stretch to).

For more information, read a good flex tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. The explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.wrapper > div:not(.header).row {
    flex: 1;                         /* 1 */
    display: flex;                   /* 1 */
}

div.large-7.columns {
    display: flex;                   /* 2 */
}

div.image-container {                /* 3 */
     flex: 1;
}

div.large-5.show-for-medium {        /* 4 */
     align-self: flex-start;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kkb2bxu/55/)

Notes:

1. flex container and items consume all remaining height of respective parents
2. give children full height (via `align-items: stretch` initial setting)
3. flex item consumes all available width
4. yellow box does not need to expand to full height; now set to content height